# Multivalue fields eval functions in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have multiple event_names ending in  COPIED & SELECTED
As part of the analysis I'm doing, I need to rename the events ending with COPIED based on certain criterias

For Example

```
Mail_Copied = where Email Copied
Text_Copied = where Text Copied
Text_Email_Copied = where both Text_Copied and Email_Copied are used 
UK_Number_Selected = Where the phone number is UK Phone
Non_UK_Number_Selected = Where the phone number is not UK phone number
```

I've done my eval as such

```
| eval Channel=case(event_name==Mail_Copied, EmailCopied, event_name==Text_Copied, *TextCopied*,
 (event_name==Mail_Copied OR  event_name==Text_Copied), TextEmailCopied,
 (event_name==Text_Copied AND event_name==UK_Number_Selected), UK_Number,
 (event_name==Text_Copied AND event_name==Non_UK_Number_Selected), NON_UK_Number)
| stats count as "Number" by month, Channel, event_name
```

The issue I have is that most of the events come from COPIED event, however because I have to use the combination of the SELECTED events with COPIED events, its not returning any value for UK_Number and NON_UK_Number

| Month | Channel | event_name | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| November | Non_UK_Number | Non_UK_Number_Selected | 463 |
| November | TextCopied | Text_Copied | 34 |
| November | EmailCopied | Email_Copied | 4 |
| November | TextEmailCopied | Text_Email_Copied | 10 |

I am not sure if I've explained myself clearly.

Comment: can you share some sample data? I have an idea that avoids using a `case`, but need to be sure before suggesting it

Answer (score 1):

The `case` function is order-sensitive.  The first match is the one used even if another match also evaluates to `true`.  Try re-arranging the evaluations.

```
| eval Channel=case(
 (event_name==Mail_Copied AND event_name==Text_Copied), TextEmailCopied,
 (event_name==Text_Copied AND event_name==UK_Number_Selected), UK_Number,
 (event_name==Text_Copied AND event_name==Non_UK_Number_Selected), NON_UK_Number,
  event_name==Mail_Copied, EmailCopied,
  event_name==Text_Copied, *TextCopied*)
```

Comment: Thanks @RichG i found a workaround that sovled the problem. Also you comment is valid